# How to get string from in between 2 strings

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

I am currently trying to get a string that is in between 2 substrings. In this case the string I need to manipulate is a block of code. Not sure if it is the regex or the search function but i keep getting none back and I shouldn't. I need to get the Offset on line 53 but I need to use Gusset To Backplate Left Gus 1 as the start marker and ENDFOR I think could be the end marker. Just not quite sure how to the syntax for something like this would work in python. I have tried some of the examples that I have seen online and have had no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated. Also I would like to do it with compile being that the offsets could be accessed multiple times.

```
s = '''!GUSSET TO BACKPLATE LEFT GUS 1 ;
45:  E_NO(8) ;
46:  FOR R[191:COUNTER B]=1 TO R[199:CHANNELS] ;
47:   ;
48:  CALL CHAN_BP_TO_GR    ;
49:   ;
50:  PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]-R[197:X OFFSET MM]    ;
51:  --eg:THESE OFFSETS ONLY APPLY TO THIS BLOCK AND INCREASE THE AMOUNT GIVEN
  :  EACH LOOP ;
52:  !X OFFSET ;
53:  PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]+21    ;
54:  !Y OFFSET ;
55:  PR[GP1:2,2:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,2:OFFSET]+0    ;
56:  !Z OFFSET ;
57:  PR[GP1:2,3:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,3:OFFSET]+0    ;
58:  ENDFOR ;'''


string1 = re.compile('!GUSSET TO BACKPLATE LEFT GUS 1 ;')
string2 = re.compile('PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]+[0-9]*    ;')
string3 = re.compile('ENDFOR ;')

result = re.search(r'!GUSSET TO BACKPLATE LEFT GUS 1 ;, (PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]+[0-9]*    ;),ENDFOR ;', s)
'.(PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]+[0-9]*    ;'
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your text is multiline you will need the re.M flag.

To use . to match newline you also need the re.DOTALL flag.

!GUSSET.*PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]=  will match all text up to the OFFSET on line 53  then we match anything that's not a space or ; and save that to be returned by result.group(1) as shown below.

(?!ENDFOR).*ENDFOR.*   will match anything thats not ENDFOR followed by ENDFOR
This should prevent it from being too greedy and limit the match to this specific section and not span multiple ENDFOR's.

try

```
result = re.search('!GUSSET.*PR\[GP1:2,1:OFFSET\]=([^; ]+)(?!ENDFOR).*ENDFOR.*', s,re.M|re.DOTALL)
print(result.group(1))
```

this will return

```
PR[GP1:2,1:OFFSET]+21
```

Comment: Does this multiline rule hold true if the string in question was in a text file as well?

Comment: A text file is just text. If the text file has newline chars [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline ] and you want to search across multiple lines then you need the multiline flag and the dotall flag.

Comment: I have been messing with this off and on for a few days here. And it seems to me that somehow looking for it in a file it always returns a none value. However when using the code you provided in the string that put directly in the program it acts fine. I am accessing the file correctly also because there are no issues with reading or writing. And with other regex I can access certain things. Just can't seem to get the string between strings figured out.

Comment: NVD. It was not working when I tried to loop through the file text. It's working now though.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Just whenever I tried to loop through the file it was giving me a bunch of none values. (Was not finding the string) but when accessing it with, with open it worked. Now I having some issues getting it to work with my tkinter. Ffpath = open()